# PHP - Increase Soap Client Execution time

Tags: php, soap

I am using soap client class. After running for sometime, it stops executing. I think the problem is with execution time. I used the following methods to increase the execution time.

```
Method-1 : $client = new SoapClient($myUrl, array('connection_timeout' => 1500));

Method-2 : ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 1500);

Method-3 : try {
        $client->WaitBeforeResponse(1500);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

But none of them worked. For method-3, it shows the error

*Function ("WaitBeforeResponse") is not a valid method for this service*

Is there any working method to increase the execution time of soap client?

Comment: Have you increased your script execution time with set_time_limit? It defaults to 30 seconds and could be causing the stopped execution. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: yes.. But did not work